# JSP vs Servlet For Generating Dropdown List

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to generate a Drop down list using values from a property file. Currently my program is setup to have an HTML page with a hard coded drop down list with a submit button. When the button is clicked the "work" is all done in the servlet itself(and additional java classes). I wanted to do this using javascript or jquery but I cannot seem to find any information on how to do this.

The two solutions I can think of are 1)switching the html to jsp and putting the java code in the jsp file to generate the ddl or 2)use a servlet to write html code with the proper values to a page.

I am just looking for some guidance as to what would be the best way. Maybe there is a 3rd option that is even better?

Comment: Could we see your current code?

Comment: The current code that I am talking about is simply an html page with a drop down menu and a button. I can paste it if you would like. The servlet side is just a page servlet file that calls backend functions. Let me know if you want me to paste it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond this one dropdown, assuming there is more to this webapp than just this (other forms, fields, additional pages?) then maybe a longer term solution would be to look at using a web framework that would provide support for handling this for you, as well as many other of the typical features you are going to need to build your web app. You could look at Spring MVC, JSF, or investigate something more 'modern web app'-like by using JAX-RS resources serverside and jQuery or some other Javascript library or framework (AngularJS?) on the frontend.

Comment: Thank you for your post. The web app does have more but the front end is really 3 pages. Index which has 4 links (1 to each other page). The other pages all the user to add data to the property file, edit the property file, and delete items from the property file. The majority of the program is on the backend which uses mainframe files as inputs and generates excel documents from them. Would you still suggest looking into one of these frameworks?

Comment: Sorry I meant 5 not 3 pages

Comment: I think it would make it easier in the long run to use a framework. It's always hard to say for a small/trivial app... at somepoint in the future are there going to be enhancements to add 1 more page, and then another page.. if so then at this point you (or the next guy) will be thankful you chose a framework in the first place.

Comment: Alright, I will look into it. These will allow me to add a dynamic amount of items to the drop down list at runtime correct?

Comment: Sure, if you're building the content for the dropdown serverside, and then the frontend is displaying the content retrieved. Most frameworks allow you to bind the content of the dropdown (or any field) to some value that is initialized serverside, replacing the static HTML approach that you have right now.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can do it with JSP, but I think servlet would be better. As you said the default values should read from a properties file, so you can read it once only in servlet init, and in doGet set up 2 parameters like (level=1,2,3 & name=a,b,c) to generate a proper JSON output as you want.

on browser end it's quite simple to do it with JQuery, like this

`$("#drop-list-id").on('changed', function() {      $.getJSON('/servlet/level=1').success(function(json) { ... });
});`

Comment: Or use a JAX-RS resource instead of a Servlet to handle generating/mapping Java objects to JSON for you.

Comment: @yjyqin I understand most of what you are saying but I am a little confused by the 2 parameters part. In you example would 'level' and 'name' be variables inside of a loop or something? Are they arrays? I am not entirely sure how to implement the servlet side of what you are saying

Comment: @KevinHooke I will have to check that out. I have never used restful but it cant hurt to look at it lol

Comment: @xCasper no parameter used if you want to return all values in single json request, or your drop list only has one level. If it's multiple level, usually three in many places, then need few parameters to make droplist updating dynamically when selected value changed.